# Как использовать наследование если классы вложенные?

Tags: java

Есть 6 классов.

one two three four five six

они все последовательно подключены.

Как изменить метод Data в классе six, с использованием класса one?

Если в каждом последующем классе прописано

```
void Data(String str){
super(str);
}
```

И лишь в классе Six

```
void Data(String str){
Код из 20 строк.
}
```

Наследование тот не поможет как я понял?

Comment: А что значит «они все последовательно подключены»?

Comment: ничерта непонятно. что значит "они все последовательно подключены"? мы тут слишком глупые чтобы понять. код в студию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

что такое "последовательно подключенные" ? термин вижу впервые. Это не "подключение", а **наследование**. Изобретать свою терминологию - мерзость. По сабжу - 
используй рефлексию. Взято отсюда [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456177/calling-super-super-class-method)

```
Class superSuperClass = this.getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass();
superSuperClass.getMethod("foo").invoke(this);
```

Answer (score 3):

Это не разрешено делать намеренно, поскольку это бы нарушило инкапсуляцию.

Вы не должны иметь возможность обойти поведение, прописанное в вашем родительском классе. Когда вы наследуете `C6` от `C5`, вы тем самым говорите, что `C6` есть разновидность `C5`. Если бы было легко было обойти наследование, и использовать методы любого из предков, то у программиста был бы соблазн не дополнять поведение базового класса, а полностью игнорировать его. Как язык высокого уровня, Java не поддерживает паттерны, нарушающие логику наследования. Используя вызов метода дальнего предка, ваш код скорее всего нарушит, например, [принцип подстановки Лисков](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B_%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Разумеется, вы можете *обойти* это ограничение, используя внеязыковые средства (например, рефлексию). Но если вам нужно делать такое, скорее всего ваш дизайн неверен.

---

<sub>По мотивам [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/586397/276994)</sub>

---

P.S.: В следующий раз, если вас не затруднит, постарайтесь избегать оскорблений других людей, особенно если ваши знания предметной области не на высоте.